# Windows tab header font messed up

Tags: windows, fonts, notepad++, scaling

Some of my Windows 10 fonts are messed up. I have reset all DPI scaling, font settings, themes etc. but cannot get rid of this problem. See this image as an example: [http://imgur.com/6vvlChs](https://imgur.com/6vvlChs)

Note that this is not limited to Notepad++. Is there a registry setting I can edit or any other way to fix the problem?

Comment: What other apps are affected in this way?  And, so far as you can tell, are *only* tabs affected?  Other things like buttons, text boxes, etc. are OK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ tabs font size](https://superuser.com/questions/1211938/notepad-tabs-font-size)